# Determine whether any permutation of a given array exists such that the sum of all subarrays of length K are equal

Tags: python, algorithm, array

I was asked this question in an interview.

> You are given an array consisting of N integers. You need to determine whether any permutation of a given array exists such that the sum of all subarrays of length K are equal. N is divisible by K i.e. N mod K = 0.
>   If the array is [1,2,1,3,2,3] and K = 2, it is False.
>   If the array is [1,2,1,3,2,3] and K = 3, it is True.

My logic was this.

> 1. If N == K, return True.
> 2. Else store each of the distinct element in the array in a
>      dictionary. If the number of distinct elements in the dictionary
>      is greater than K, return False.
> 3. Else store the count of each distinct element in the dictionary.
> 4. If the count of any distinct element is less than (N/K), return False.
> 5. Finally return True.

Here is my code in Python:

```
def check(nums, n, k):
if n == k:
    return True
else:
    my_dict = {}
    for i in nums:
        if i not in my_dict:
            my_dict[i] = 1
        else:
            my_dict[i] += 1
    if len(my_dict) > k:
        return False
    count = int(n/k)
    for i,j in my_dict.items():
        if j < count:
            return False
    return True
```

Am I doing the right approach ?

Comment: How about `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, and `K = 2`?

Comment: It will return False. All the possible subarrays (including the permutations of the given array) of length 2 are [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4] and [3,4]. We can see that the sum of each of these subarrays are not equal.

Comment: @GarethRees Sir, in your example N = 8 and K = 3. This input will be invalid since 8 mod 3 != 0.

Comment: **Define subarray**. Is it a contiguous set (e.g. for ABCDE, the only valid subarrays (K=3) are ABC, BCD and CDE) or non-contiguous (e.g. ACD is also considered a subarray)? No matter what definition you use, I cannot make heard or tails of your true/false examples. Can you show us a specific (exhaustive) list of all subarrays from a given example; and an explanation why this is true/false?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`collections.Counter`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/collections#collections.Counter) instead of keeping a count yourself.

When you have counted all the elements from the list, check if any of their counts is not a factor of \$ N \$ and return `False`.

Therefore:

```
from collections import Counter

def check(nums, n, k):
    if n == k:
        return True
    counts = Counter(nums)
    if len(counts) > k:
        return False
    return all((n % x == 0 for x in counts.values()))
```